# Align sibling divs right while jQuery expands width

Tags: jquery, css, hover, jquery-animate

http://jsfiddle.net/imHavoc/b8Ktj/10/

The problem is when one div's width expands so does the bounding div, which all the siblings are "left aligned" to. I cannot figure out how to keep the sibling divs aligned to the right while one div's width expands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `float: right` and `clear: right` to `div.navScroll`.

The demo you made after my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/imHavoc/b8Ktj/11/